# New to CiviCRM: Hosting (VPS) requirements and migration from NationBuilder

Tags: migration, hosting

this is my first question to the forum, hope you can help me. My org wants to migrate from NationBuilder to CiviCRM. We currently have a shared hosting solution with GreenGeeks, so:

Question 1: with about 6,000 members, contributors... and sending about 50,000 mails a month, do you think a hosting solution like the 1GB option here would be good for a CiviCRM + Wordpress installation? https://www.greengeeks.com/vps-hosting/

Question 2: we'd like to migrate from NationBuilder to CiviCRM. Do you know of any guide/tutorial for this specific case?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Joaquin - welcome - usually best to ask a single question per thread so that it can actually get answered clearly.

Answer (score 2):

Q2 JMA Consulting and Fuzion recently migrated a large db from NB to CiviCRM + Drupal. JMA built the migration mapping. Fuzion worked on a Drupal-side interface that replicated some of the common NB screens (so not relevant for WP sites). You may want to get in touch with JMA via the Partners list concerning the migration side of things.

NOTE: If this is seen as too 'advertorial' then pls down vote it and I will happily remove it.

Comment: Thanks petednz, I've contacted JMA. Let's see if they can help!